# ¿Como solucionar el error segmentation fault (core dumped) cuando se imprime strtok?

Tags: c

He estado investigando acerca de este error que me aparece cuando intento compilar las siguientes lineas por ejemplo:

```
char cadena[] = "hola mundo";
char * div = " ";
char * token = strtok(cadena, div);
while (token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, div);
}
```

y cuando se ejecuta... llega a ese punto y aparece el error segmentation fault (core dumped), se que anteriormente también han tratado aca el mismo tema, pero en cada una no he logrado encontrar una solución que me permita utilizar este comando, lo que intento es en code blocks tomar una cadena de texto y dividirla en tokens para verificar que es lo que se ha ingresado, de antemano agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿hay algún otro código en tu programa?  lo he compilado y funciona como se espera, sin ningún error..

Comment: pues como tenia ese problema solo lo deje con ese codigo dentro del main:
 
<blink>
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){

 char cadena[] = "hola mundo";
char * div = " ";
char * token = strtok(cadena, div);
while (token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, div);
}
return 0;
}
</blink>

Comment: pues como tenia ese problema solo lo deje con ese codigo dentro del main:
 
                                                           
                                 
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


int main(void){

 char cadena[] = "hola mundo";
char * div = " ";
char * token = strtok(cadena, div);
while (token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, div);
}
return 0;
}
                                                                 
me imagino que ha de ser algo independiente al lenguaje en si, porque me sigue dando el mismo error.

Answer (score 1):

Según parece estás olvidando incluir el header `string.h`. El compilador no encuentra la declaración de `strtok()` y en tal caso (quizás [sorprendentemente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687508/why-does-c-tolerate-missing-function-declarations)) no tira error sino que compila la llamada a la función asumiendo una *declaración implícita*. Esta declaración implícita la construye con los argumentos que encuentra en el primer uso, y con **valor de retorno `int`**. Ahora bien, en etapa de link (enlazado), el compilador encuentra el "verdadero" `strtok`, que (como sabemos) retorna un puntero. Por lo tanto, al correr el programa todo probablemente funcionará (de casualidad, por decirlo así) si el puntero tiene el mismo tamaño que un `int` - lo cual depende de tu [arquitectura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models). Si no es así, el puntero será inválido y probablemente fallará.

Puede verificar esta explicación (tentativa), imprimiendo los tamaños `sizeof(int)` y `sizeof(char*)`

Dependiendo del compilador que estés usando, suele haber opciones para cambiar el comportamiento, de manera de tirar un error cuando uno olvida incluir el header. En cualquier caso, siempre se recomienda (y mucho más cuando tenemos problemas que no terminamos de entender) obligar al compilador a emitir todas alarmas ("warnings")... y no pasarlas por alto.